# Aws s3 putObject is doing both a option request and a put request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am doing a direct form upload to aws s3 like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < imgUploadList.length; i++) {
    var params = {
              Key: 'images/' + imgUploadList[i].id + '/' + imgUploadList[i].img.name,
              ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
              Body: imgUploadList[i].img,
              ACL: 'public-read'
            };

            bucket.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              } else {
                //Run callback when all images are uploaded
                imagesUploaded.push("dummy"); //Just to end loop when all images are done
                if (imagesUploaded.length === imgUploadList.length) {
                  console.log("done ulpoading");
                  callback();
                }
              }

}
```

But even when I am only uploading one image aws does two requests, one option and one put see the img

[image]

Why is it doing two request for each image?
Like in this example I only uploaded one image but I can see that AWS does a options request then a put request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

"Additionally, for HTTP request methods that can cause side-effects on server's data (in particular, for HTTP methods other than GET, or for POST usage with certain MIME types), the specification mandates that browsers "preflight" the request, soliciting supported methods from the server with an HTTP OPTIONS request method, and then, upon "approval" from the server, sending the actual request with the actual HTTP request method."